# Up navigation goes to main activity

Tags: android

I have the following Androidmanifest file

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".First"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_first"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="android.anoop.com.myapplication.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Second"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_second"
        android:parentActivityName=".First" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="android.anoop.com.myapplication.First" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

In main activity's onCreate method i have the following code to launch Second activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent1=new Intent(this,Second.class);
    startActivity(intent1);
}
```

Other than that every other activities code is what android studio provide as default. But when i press up button from the Second activity it goes directly to main activity and not to the First activity. I know there are alternate solutions for this problem but i just want to know why the up navigation is behaving like this.I am new to android so i may not be understanding something really simple. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using calling SecondActivity in onCreate of FirstActivity, then it goes to SecondActivity. But think about it, when do an Activity actually starts?

It starts after you call onCreate, then onStart , then onResume and then your Actiivity finally starts running. In your case, you are not allowing to go further onCreate, and hence FirstActivity has never even started. And thats why when you go back in navigation it jumps to the previously opened Activity, i.e., MainActivity.

I hope this clears your answer! For reference see the Lificycle of an Activity in this [link.](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/activity_lifecycle/Images/image2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Because **FirstActivity is not started or Created**. You are calling Second directly from Main Activity. As there is no any First Activity available in application's stack how Second Activity goes to parent Activity First? It will goes to Main Activity as Its the only Activity remain in stack.

Comment: thanks ,but is there a way to add FirstActivity to stack without creating or starting it

Comment: Nope. Without stating that activity you can't.